# Average daily values for 30 year period with adjacents days

Tags: r, mean, sliding

I have gridded (10km grid) daily mean temeperatures from 19610101 to 19901231 in a netcdf file.
I would like to calculate statistical 30 year values (mean etc.) so that for example 4th of Jan should
have values from 1st of Jan to 7th of Jan from every year 1961...1990 : each grid point and day should have 210 values.

Original grid size is 68(x) * 116 (y) * 10957 (days) and the final grid size is 68 * 116 * 365.

The script below works, but is slow. Could you please tell me a better solution,
so I would be able to calculate statistical values also for 1km grid.

```
days <- ncvar_get(nc_in,"Time")

days.px <- as.POSIXlt(days,formt="%d-%m-%")



for (year_day in 0:364) { 

  days_in_interest <- (year_day - 3):(year_day + 3)

  days_in_interest[which(days_in_interest < 0)] <- 365 + days[which(days_in_interest < 0)]

  days_in_interest[which(days_in_interest > 364)] <- days_in_interest[which(days_in_interest >364)] - 364

  t_values <- grid_values[,,which((days.px$yday%in%days_in_interest )&days.px$yday!=365)]
 
  t_mean <- apply(t_values , c(1,2), mean) # grid point mean 

}
```

Comment: Please tidy up your question. Make it clear what language you are using etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived easily using CDO:

```
cdo runmean,7 infile outfile
```

Comment: Thank you, seems very clear! And if I want to calculate percentiles 5% and 95% for every year day?

Comment: I tried, but this was not exactly what I wanted: average mean over 30 years period for every year day (1...365). This could be nice starting data for mean calculations, but it is not suitable for percentile calculations.

Comment: If you want guidance on how to calculate percentiles please ask a question on SO